# How exactly do I create this Tallying program?

Tags: python

I get this error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"
when I try to run this code. it's on the x += 1 line.
The goal of this program is to receive input such as "RA1" or "R04" and add 1 to the value, which always starts at 0. I then want it to "print" the results when I type END. This is proving to be quite the challenge. Python 3.5.1

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0



print("Enter 3 digit code.")

x = str(input())

while x != "END":

if x == "RA1":

    x += 1

    continue

elif x == "R04":

    y += 1

    continue

elif x == "etc":

    z += 1

    continue

else:

    print('Please enter a 3 digit value or END')
```

Comment: You need an >>explicit<< conversion ....

Comment: You have *way* too many blank lines. The only blank lines you need are maybe 1 before the first `print`, and one before the `while`. The rest can go, and your code will be more readable for it. Your indentation is also off (`if` and `elif` are inside the `while` loop, so they need one more level of indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems in your code.

The cause of the TypeError was that you unintentionally made x a string by writing `x = str(input())` and when you wanted to add `1` to it, Python tried to convert `1` to a string to concatenate it to x.

The infinite loop was unrelated to the TypeError you received. It occurred because of the misplacement of the `str(input())` call.

This is the working code with the fixed while loop:

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
i = ""

print("Enter 3 digit code.")

while i != "END":
    i = input()
    if i == "RA1":
        x += 1
    elif i == "R04":
        y += 1
    elif i == "etc":
        z += 1
    else:
        print('Please enter a 3 digit value or END')

print(str(x) + " " + str(y) + " " + str(z))
```

Comment: Brings me into an infinite loop, same with the other answer

Comment: @gabrielscharf I edited my answer. You have to stop the loop by accepting a new input.

Comment: @Kris , I'm not sure what you mean, could you explain a little deeper?

Comment: I also edited my answer because I realized you probably wanted to achieve something entirely different.

Comment: There's no need to do `str(input())` because `input` returns a string. And you don t need those `continue`s, either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your integers into strings by wrapping each with `str()`.
Afterwards, use `x = raw_input()` for your inputs. When you first enter the loop, you need to take an input, but also when you loop back around. So, therefore, you need a way to stop your infinite loop. Hence, `x = raw_input()` needs to be added at the start of the loop.

You can actually just get your input at the start of the loop, there's no need for 2.

Additionally, your x, y and z should also just be empty strings or null, not `0`.

```
x = ""
y = ""
z = ""




while x != "END":

    print("Enter 3 digit code.")

    x = raw_input()

    if x == "RA1":

        x += str(1)

        continue

    if x == "R04":

        y += str(1)

        continue

    elif x == "etc":

        z += str(1)

        continue

    else:

        print('Please enter a 3 digit value or END')
```